# Sunmi v2 does not print special characters

Tags: sunmi

Every time I print and in the print there is a special character type è ì the print stops and they exit -------

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We have a delivery application, and in the names of the products where there are special characters such as ì ò, when the merchant prints it as soon as he reads the special characters the printing is blocked